# Startup error (line 119 and 121) Ubuntu

Tags: bashrc, error-handling

I'm having a startup error when logging into Ubuntu (through XQuartz). I'm new at this and do not understand how to fix the problem yet. I've tried to look for solutions without any luck so far.
Do you have any suggestions?

The errors I am getting are stated below:

```
-bash: /home/ubuntu/.bashrc: line 119: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

-bash: /home/ubuntu/.bashrc: line 121: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Output of `grep -n '"' .bashrc`:

```
26:# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
31:[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
34:if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
38:# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
39:case "$TERM" in
48:if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
59:if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
67:case "$TERM" in
69:    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
77:    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval 
"$(dircolors -b)"
95:# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
97:alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || 
echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0- 
9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
119:export PATH="$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

Comment: Maybe for some reason some text leaked from the terminal into the file.<br>
Please provoide us the file /home/ubuntu/.bashrc

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! As the error messages state, there is some bad code in your `.bashrc` file. Please [edit] your question to include (the relevant part of) the file.

Comment: Well I am not sure I actually have a bachrc. file. I am working through an external server, and by looking through the files in Filezilla I can not seem to find it.

Comment: @Sineik you will need to configure Filezilla to *show hidden files*

Comment: @steeldriver I just did but there was no change. I still can not locate bashrc for some reason

Comment: @Sineik As you can see `"` is missing from the end in line 119, either manually edit this file using text editor like nano, gedit and put `"` at the end or you can do it with `sed`. Run `sed -i '119s/$/"/' .bashrc`.

Comment: @Kulfy That seemed to do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output it seems `"` is missing in the end of line 119. Use either of the method to put `"`.

- Open .bashrc using some text editor like nano, gedit or pico, and add `"` at the end of the line 119.
- Or simply run:

  ```bsh
  sed -i '119s/$/"/' .bashrc
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an unterminated "`"`" around line 119 that is still unterminated when you get to the end of the script. Carefully inspect lines around line 119, and make sure you have an even number of `"`s.

When I get this type of error, I do

```
grep -n '"' .bashrc
```